# Scipy ndimage.convolve skips the summation of channels

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, conv-neural-network, convolution

I'm trying to use `scipy`'s `ndimage.convolve` function to perform a convolution on a 3 dimensional image (RGB, width, height).

Taking a look here:

[image: http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/]

It is clear to see that for any input, each kernel/filter should only ever have an output of **NxN**, with strictly a depth of 1.

This is a problem with `scipy`, as when you do `ndimage.convolve` with an input of size `(3, 5, 5)` and a filter/kernel of size `(3, 3, 3)`, the result of this operation produces an output size of `(3, 5, 5)`, clearly not summing the different channels.

Is there a way to force this summation without manually doing so? I try to do as little in base python as possible, as a lot of external libraries are written in c++ and do the same operations faster. Or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No scipy doesn't skip the summation of channels. The reason why you get a `(3, 5, 5)` output is because `ndimage.convolve` is padding the input array along all the axes and then performs convolution in the "same" mode (i.e. the output has the same shape as input, centered with respect to the output of the "full" mode correlation). See the [scipy.signal.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) for more detail on modes.

For your input of shape `(3 ,5, 5)` and filter `w0` of shape `(3, 3, 3)`, the input is padded resulting in a `(7, 9, 9)` array. See below (for simplicity I use constant padding with 0's):

```
a = np.array([[[2, 0, 2, 2, 2],
               [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 2, 2],
               [2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
               [1, 0, 1, 2, 0]],

              [[1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
               [0, 2, 0, 0, 1],
               [0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
               [2, 0, 1, 0, 2],
               [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]],

              [[0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
               [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 2, 0],
               [0, 2, 0, 0, 2],
               [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]]])

w0 = np.array([[[0,  1, -1],
                [1, -1,  0],
                [0,  0,  0]],

               [[1,  0,  0],
                [0, -1,  1],
                [1,  0,  1]],

               [[ 1, -1,  0],
                [-1,  0, -1],
                [-1,  0,  1]]])

k = w0.shape[0]

a_p = np.pad(a, k-1)

array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

Before proceeding, note that in the image from cs231n what is performed is correlation and not convolution, so we need to flip the `w0` or instead use correlation function (I will do the former).

Then, the convolution is performed by sliding along the first dimension (axis-0), i.e. the (flipped) `w0` is convolved with `a_p[0:3]`, then with `a_p[1:4]`, then with `a_p[2:5]`, then with `a_p[3:6]` and finally with `a_p[4:7]`, each resulting in a `(1, 7, 7)` array due to summation over the channels. Then they are stacked together resulting in `(5, 7, 7)` array. To show this I use `scipy.signal.convolve` which allows to use the `full` mode:

```
out = scipy.signal.convolve(a, np.flip(w0), mode='full')

array([[[ 2,  0,  0,  2,  0, -2, -2],
        [-1,  1, -5, -1, -4, -4, -2],
        [-1, -3,  2, -3,  1, -4,  0],
        [ 2,  1, -1, -3, -7,  0, -2],
        [-1, -2, -4, -1, -4, -2,  2],
        [-1, -2, -2, -2,  1, -2,  0],
        [ 0, -1,  1, -1, -1,  2,  0]],

       [[ 3,  2,  4,  0,  4,  2,  1],
        [ 2, -1,  1, -1, -1,  0, -2],
        [ 1, -3,  3,  5,  2,  1,  3],
        [ 4,  2,  1,  4,  0, -3, -2],
        [ 1,  1,  1, -1, -1,  3, -1],
        [ 1, -4,  3, -1, -3, -4,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  1,  2,  2]],

       [[ 1,  2,  4,  4,  2, -2, -1],
        [ 1,  2,  1, -3, -4, -4,  1],
        [-2,  2, -3,  3,  1,  2,  4],
        [ 1,  2,  5, -6,  6, -2,  3],
        [ 2, -5,  4,  1,  5,  4,  0],
        [-2,  0,  0,  1, -3, -4,  3],
        [-1,  1, -1, -2,  4,  3,  3]],

       [[ 0,  0,  2,  2,  4,  2,  2],
        [ 0,  0,  3,  3,  3, -2,  1],
        [-1,  0,  0,  4,  0,  4,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  2,  3,  1,  3,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  7,  1,  3],
        [-2,  2,  0,  2, -3,  1,  4],
        [ 0, -1, -1,  0,  2,  4,  1]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0,  2],
        [ 0,  0, -3, -1,  1,  3,  0],
        [ 0, -1, -1,  1, -1,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  0, -2,  0,  2, -2,  2],
        [ 0, -2,  2, -2, -2,  3,  1],
        [ 0,  0, -2,  0,  1,  1,  0]]])
```

To get into the "same" mode of `ndimage.convolve` we need to center the `out`:

```
out = out[1:-1, 1:-1, 1:-1]

array([[[-1,  1, -1, -1,  0],
        [-3,  3,  5,  2,  1],
        [ 2,  1,  4,  0, -3],
        [ 1,  1, -1, -1,  3],
        [-4,  3, -1, -3, -4]],

       [[ 2,  1, -3, -4, -4],
        [ 2, -3,  3,  1,  2],
        [ 2,  5, -6,  6, -2],
        [-5,  4,  1,  5,  4],
        [ 0,  0,  1, -3, -4]],

       [[ 0,  3,  3,  3, -2],
        [ 0,  0,  4,  0,  4],
        [ 0,  2,  3,  1,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  7,  1],
        [ 2,  0,  2, -3,  1]]])
```

This is exactly what you get if you run `scipy.ndimage.convolve(a, np.flip(w0), mode='constant', cval=0)`. Finally, to get the desired output we need to ignore the elements that relied on padding along the first dimension (i.e. keep only the middle part of the out), also use strides `s=2` (i.e. `out[1][::s, ::s]`), and finally add the bias `b = 1`:

```
out[1][::s, ::s] + b

array([[ 3, -2, -3],
       [ 3, -5, -1],
       [ 1,  2, -3]])
```

Putting everything in one line:

```
scipy.ndimage.convolve(a, np.flip(w0), mode='constant', cval=0)[1][::2, ::2] + b

# or using scipy.signal.convolve
# scipy.signal.convolve(a, np.flip(w0), 'full')[2][1:-1,1:-1][::2, ::2] + b
# or
# scipy.signal.convolve(a, np.flip(w0), 'same')[1][::2, ::2] + b
```

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly high quality answer! Just as another related question, would you happen to know why a convolution is used instead of a correlation in machine learning? Last year I accidentally created a correlation neural network and it learnt just fine, so I'm curious why the flipping of the filter is so important

Comment: In the true convolution the kernel is flipped relative to the input, however this flipping is unnecessary in CNNs because the kernel values are learned, so this extra operation can be just skipped (so convolution becomes cross-correlation). The reason why in machine learning it is called convolution is perhaps historical, maybe at first some libraries were using the true convolution but later removed the flipping part keeping the name of operation... In any case, both operations can be used in CNNs.

Comment: Just revisiting this question a year later - I found through testing that if you use a correlation on the forward pass you end up using a convolution in the backward pass to learn the parameters, and visa-versa if you use a convolution on the forward pass.